# Python pandas read list in list data type from csv file

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a csv file, like this:

```
A       B
aaa     [['a1','b1'],['a2','b2']]
bbb     [['a3','b3']]
```

I tried to read this file into python. And I want the 'B' column in list data type.
I tried 
`pd.read_csv('filename.csv')`, what I got is `"[['a1','b1'],['a2','b2']]"` in str type, not in list type.
And I also tried `pd.read_csv('filename.csv', converters={'B':list})`, what I got here is like: [[, [',a','1,','b,'...., not the list I want.
Could you tell me how to read the list from a csv file directly? Thank you so much.

Comment: can you share csv file

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is caused by the serialization format of the `list` in column *B*. It is stored as a string representation of the list. In order to recover a python list back from the string, you can use [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) as a converter:

```
df = pd.read_csv(source, converters={'B': eval})
```

Answer (score 0):

to read list you should try this

```
import csv
with open('filename.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    your_list = list(reader)

print your_list
```

Answer (score 0):

I use pandas to handle file easily.
If you can decide what gets in your file, you could also choose to store something like this:

```
A,B
aaa,a1 b1 + a2 b2
bbb,a3 b3
```

Then you can simply read your file and use the power of the split function which will:

- split your string with the seperator of your choice (white space by default)
- return the result in a list object.

For your second colum of the first row, you can simply run split once with the white space as a seperator and run it again with '+' as a seperator.

You can find more details on split here https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv('my_file.csv')
for row in df.itertuples():
  my_list = row.A.split()
```